# XML Shema: Allow for a sequence of elements and attributes on a complex type

Tags: xml, xsd

My terminology might not be right since I am new to XML.

I came up with this XML format:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-model href="RuleBuilder.xsd" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
<root>
    <RuleBuilder:game_system
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="file:///./RuleBuilder.xsd RuleBuilder.xsd"
        xmlns:RuleBuilder="file:///./RuleBuilder.xsd">
        <RuleBuilder:rule_book>
            <RuleBuilder:title>"Warhammer The Game of Fantasy Battles"</RuleBuilder:title>
            <RuleBuilder:page_count>100</RuleBuilder:page_count>
            <RuleBuilder:rule>
                <RuleBuilder:id>0</RuleBuilder:id>
                <RuleBuilder:rule_type>"character"</RuleBuilder:rule_type>
                <RuleBuilder:title>"Monsterous Infantry"</RuleBuilder:title>
                <RuleBuilder:description>"This is a test"</RuleBuilder:description>
                <RuleBuilder:page_begin>200</RuleBuilder:page_begin>
                <RuleBuilder:related_definition>0</RuleBuilder:related_definition>
            </RuleBuilder:rule>
            <RuleBuilder:definition>
                <RuleBuilder:id>0</RuleBuilder:id>
                <RuleBuilder:term>"Monsterous Infantry"</RuleBuilder:term>
                <RuleBuilder:definition>"A big bertha"</RuleBuilder:definition>
                <RuleBuilder:page_begin>200</RuleBuilder:page_begin>
                <RuleBuilder:related_rule>0</RuleBuilder:related_rule>
            </RuleBuilder:definition>
        </RuleBuilder:rule_book>
    </RuleBuilder:game_system>
</root>
```

Which validates just fine against this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" xmlns="RuleBuilder"
    targetNamespace="RuleBuilder" elementFormDefault="qualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:element name="game_system">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="rule_book" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>         
                            <xs:element name="page_count" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="rule" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>          
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="rule_type" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="descrpiption" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="page_begin" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="related_definition" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
                                        <xs:element name="related_rule" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="definition" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="term" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="definition" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="page_begin" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="related_definition" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
                                        <xs:element name="related_rule" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

**QUESTION:** What I want to know how to do is modify the schema such that I can add attributes to some of the elements which "wrap" complex types. For examle:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>

...
<root>
    <RuleBuilder:game_system
        <RuleBuilder:rule_book
            title="Warhammer Fantasy"> <!-- Notice that I move the title here -->
            ....
        </RuleBuilder:rule_book>
    </RuleBuilder:game_system>
</root>
```

Comment: Actually your instance does not validate with that schema. One block is missing `related_rule`. The other is missing `related_definition`. Is it your schema which is to be fixed or your instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the attribute you just need to include an `xs:attribute` declaration in the `xs:complexType` of your `rule_book` element declaration:

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>         
        <xs:element name="page_count" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="rule" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="RuleType"/>
        <xs:element name="definition" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="DefinitionType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

It still won't validate. You have to decide what the rule for the `related_definition` and `related_rule` elements are. As they are declared, the instance you provided will not validate, since one of each is missing from both blocks.

In the complete schema below (which validates your source), I added `minOccurs="0"` to both of them so the instance will validate. I also placed the types outside the element declarations, to make the file more readable.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1"
           xmlns="RuleBuilder" targetNamespace="RuleBuilder" elementFormDefault="qualified" >

    <xs:element name="game_system">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="rule_book" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="RuleBookType" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="RuleBookType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>         
            <xs:element name="page_count" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="rule" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="RuleType"/>
            <xs:element name="definition" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="DefinitionType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="RuleType">          
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="rule_type" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="page_begin" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="related_definition" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="related_rule" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="DefinitionType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="term" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="definition" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="page_begin" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="related_definition" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="related_rule" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: How do I add restrictions around the attributes inside the complex type?

Comment: You can define a `simpleType` either anonymously nested inside `<xs:attribute><xs:simpleType>...</xs:simpleType></xs:attribute>` or named at top-level `<xs:simpleType name="TitleAttributeType">...</xs:simpleType>` which you can refer to as the `type` of the attribute in its declaration `<xs:attribute ... type="TitleAttributeType" />`. Then inside `xs:simpleType` you can define a `<xs:restriction>` of the base type (string), like max length, certain values (enumeration) or even regular expression.